# Isolating where clause in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
RoseFlowersData = (from c in dbContext.ClientFirst
                     where c.RoseFlower.Id == Id
                     select new FlowerDTO
                     {
                         flowerId = c.Id,
                         flowerCatergory = c.flowerCatergory
                     }),
AsterFlowerData = (from c in dbContext.ClientFirst
                       where c.AsterFlower.Id == Id
                       select new FlowerDTO
                       {
                           flowerId = c.Id,
                           flowerCatergory = c.flowerCatergory
                       }),
```

in both, the only difference is the `where` clause (`where c.RoseFlower.Id == Id;  where c.AsterFlower.Id == Id`)

I want to use following function to get me data based on different flower type (like RoseFlower, AsterFlower etc)

```
private IQueryable<FlowerDTO> GetFlowerData(int flowerId, <What should I pass here?>)
{
    var data = (from c in dbContext.ClientFirst
                where c.RoseFlower.Id == flowerId
                select new FlowerDTO
                {
                    flowerId = c.Id,
                    flowerCatergory = c.flowerCatergory
                });
    return data;
}
```

I am confused on how I can use this function for both and further flower types. I have tried looking for solutions to isolate the where clause but after hours of search, I have not been able to find a solution. Maybe I am not searching for the right thing.

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: So your `ClientFirst` has an `Id` column for every flower type? Why not just have the table have 2 columns - `FlowerTypeId` and `FlowerId` that has a foreign key to a `FlowerTypes` table? Then your signature should be `GetFlowerData(int flowerTypeId, int flowerId)` and your where clause would be `where c.FlowerTypeId == flowerTypeId and c.FlowerId == flowerId`

Comment: Changing the db is not possible at the moment, hence need to find a clever way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your LINQ to a fluid syntax using the LINQ extension methods instead:

```cs
private IQueryable<FlowerDTO> GetFlowerData(Predicate<Flower> where)
{
    var data = dbContext.ClientFirst
        .Where(where)
        .Select(c => new FlowerDTO
        {
            flowerId = c.Id,
            flowerCatergory = c.flowerCatergory
        });
    return data;
}
```

Then call your method:

```
GetFlowerData(f => f.Id == desiredFlowerId && f.FlowerType == "RoseFlower");
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Andrew H, but instead of passing `Predicate<Flower> where` as a parameter, I did passing only the Id and FlowerType, just to have less repetitions and better to maintenance:

```
private IQueryable<FlowerDTO> GetFlowerData(int id, string flowerType)
{
    var data = dbContext.ClientFirst
        .Where(f => f.Id == Id && f.FlowerType == flowerType)
        .Select(c => new FlowerDTO
        {
            flowerId = c.Id,
            flowerCatergory = c.flowerCatergory
        });
    return data;
}
```

and then:

`GetFlowerData(1, "RoseFlower");`

`GetFlowerData(2, "AsterFlower");`

Just ideas to you create your own function. Have fun.

Comment: I think this is a great solution if you only want to check the flower ID and type (and I mean that genuinely, not facetiously) since you would need to repeat the entire lambda each time you wanted to get the flower data with my more generic solution.